# How to reuse the return type of a function call inside a requires expression?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts, requires-expression

I'm writing a concept that checks if a type can be used in an expression that composes 2 functions:

```
template<typename T>
concept C = requires(T t) {
    f(g(t));
};
```

i.e., I want to check if for a given object `t` of type `T`, I can call `g(t)` and then use the resulting value as an argument to `f`. e.g.,

```
auto g(int)  -> float;   
auto g(char) -> double; 

void f(float);
void f(double) = delete;

static_assert(C<int>);       // g(int) returns a float, so f(float) is called.
static_assert(not C<char>);  // g(char) returns a double, but f(double) is deleted
```

This works just fine.

However, I want to split up the calls to `f` and `g` because 1) `g` may take additional arguments (that don't depend on `T`) resulting in a verbose call, and 2) I might want to use the return type/value of `g` multiple times inside the concept, so I don't want to repeat the call multiple times.

Naive attempts like the following

```
auto res = g(t);
f(res);
```

and

```
using ret_t = decltype(g(t));
f(ret_t{});
```

don't work inside concepts.

Is there some way to achieve the splitting up of `f(g(t))` in a way that doesn't require writing `g(t)` inside the call to `f`?

Comment: Declare an argument of the return type of `g(t)` in the parameter list like `template<typename T> concept C = requires(T t, decltype(g(t)) arg) { f(arg); }`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Hmm, that could work, although if `g(t)` is ill-formed, the concept fails in the parameters to the requires clause rather than in the body of the requires clause. Might not be a terrible option though.

Comment: @cigien even if it did fail in the parameters, such substitution failure in a concept simply means that the concept is unsatisfied, not that the program is ill-formed, so it's okay. Using `decltype(g(t))` in the parameter list is by far the shortest solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nested requirement can be an option:

```
template<typename T>
concept C = requires(T t) {
    g(t);   // Not strictly needed, I think, but explicit verification might be more readable if the concept fails in a template
    requires requires(decltype(g(t)) s) { // Can reuse s how many time we want
        f(s);
    };
};
```

And yes, requires requires is required here to make sure `f(s)` is verified as well.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, I hadn't realized requirements could be nested quite like this. (And yes, I would definitely like the explicit verification of `g(t)`). I'll try it out, thanks.